# Can you elaborate on "yum install --downlaodonly"?

Tags: installation, yum, rpm

You need to install it in an environment where there is no network.

So I was installing via RPM.

In the meantime, a crash occurred and the installation could not proceed.

I found `yum install --downloadonly` while searching for various things.

It is said that after downloading `rpm` from a network where it is possible, you can install it where the network is not possible.

If so, I have a question for you.

1. Should the OS version of the download location be the same?
2. Does it matter that the rpm's installed in the download and install places are different?
3. How does this feature's dependency resolution work? (If you don't know this, it's okay not to answer)

I need your help as I am new to `rpm` installation.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the meantime, a crash occurred and the installation could not
> proceed.

After a yum command unexpectedly stopped during a transaction, run `yum-complete-transaction` for EL7,  or `dnf history redo last`  for EL8.

If these cannot fix your package database, edit your question to add more detail on what failed, including the errors yum is printing.

---

Updates on a system without internet implies you provide an alterative repo. A local update mirror of your own. Couple ways to do that:

- Via IP: download packages to some internal http server of yours. Custom repo uses http URLs. Requires functional network on the host.
- Via "sneaker net": download packages to removable disk that can be attached to each host. Custom repo uses file:// URLs.

`yum install --downloadonly` downloads packages to the local cache as it usually does, but does not run the transaction.

`yum install`  when given file names of RPMs, will install those rather than downloading from repos. Useful for one-off ad hoc installs.

---

You need the correct packages downloaded to resolve the update transaction you are doing. There are dependencies for specific versions of things.

RPMs are archives, like tar, but actually based on cpio.  When installed, files will be extracted to the same location regardless of RPM file name. However, don't change the file name, it has useful information, and may be in the yum repo's metadata.